# Wordpress login page - lost password loop

Tags: wordpress, passwords

our customers that select 'forgot password' are currently stuck in a loop as they return to our home page. Apologies, as my lack of experience may become evident, I am taking over from the developer and did not create the website/theme - we know longer have contact with them either, so direction with them is not possible.

On our WordPress - WooCommerce page, our customers go to https://www.lacefronts.com.au/portal/ to login. If they forget their password, they select Lost Your Password option at the bottom.
[image]

This selection directs them back to our homepage.

We use a plugin called Frontend Password Reset - which provides us with short code reset-password, which we place on a page called 'Password reset'. Password reset and lost or, forgotten are all lumped into the same.

I have tried updating end points in the backend of wordpress from lost-password, password-reset, reset-password along with leaving the end point blank.

I have tried

```
 `add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'my_lostpassword_url', 10, 2 );
function my_lostpassword_url( $lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
    $redirect = '/password-reset/';
    return site_url( '/lostpassword/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}`
```

It does not work. I thought that maybe a reflection of end points, and change them again when publishing the code.